# scrapy parse function not getting called- Also bulk saving

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I found similar questions have been asked already but none of the answers explained my situation. Ans I also need help implementing the second part of my code.

here the code :

```
import scrapy
import json


 class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "myspider"

   def start_requests(self):
       urls = [
           'https://www.lin1.com',
           'https://www.link2.com'
       ]
       for url in urls:
           yield scrapy.Request(url= url,  callback=self.parse_result, meta={'url':url})

   def parse_result(self, response):
       url = response.meta['url']
       tag = response.xpath('//xxxxxxx/text()').get()
       if tag is not None:
           jsonData = json.loads(tag)
           items_list = jsonData['x']['y']['z']
           for index, item in enumerate(items_list):
                   self.parse_item(item, index + 1, url)

                ################ # IF I yield here I get some output #########################
                  # yield {
                  #      'url': url,
                  #     'index': index,
                  #     'title': item.get('name'),
                  #     'link': item.get('itemUrl'),
                  #     'item_id': item.get('itemId'),
                  #     'rating': item['rating'].get('averageRating'),
                  #     'price': item.get('price')
                  # }


           # Request Next Page
           next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get

           if next_page is not None:
               yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse_result , meta={'url': 
                     url})
               #yield scrapy.Request(url= url+next_page, callback = self.parse_result, meta= 
                   {'url': url})


   def parse_item(self, item_data, index, url):
        #############  This is not getting called ##############
        yield {
             'url': url,
             'index': index,
             'title': item_data.get('name'),
             'link': item_data.get('itemUrl'),
             'item_id': item_data.get('itemId'),
             'rating': item_data['rating'].get('averageRating'),
             'price': item_data.get('price')            
          }
```

1 - When I yield directly from the parse_result function, i get at least some output, but when I use the parse_item function, nothing is showing
2- Also, how do i put all the items from one (url) into a list before sending it to my front end?
Thanks fro the help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `parse_item` method doesn't produce any output is because you aren't yielding the output from the parse_result method.  To fix this you can easily just add a yield statement in front of the method call in your `parse_result` method. I would also change the yield in the `parse_items` to a return since you are only returning a single dictionary.

You can also get the url for the current request by simply accessing `response.url` property unless you are being redirected in which case then you can use the `response.request.url` property.

For Example:

```
   def parse_result(self, response):
       url = response.url
       tag = response.xpath('//xxxxxxx/text()').get()
       if tag is not None:
           jsonData = json.loads(tag)
           items_list = jsonData['x']['y']['z']
           for index, item in enumerate(items_list):
               yield self.parse_item(item, index + 1, url)
           next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get
           if next_page is not None:
               yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_result)
          

   def parse_item(self, item_data, index, url):
        return {
             'url': url,
             'index': index,
             'title': item_data.get('name'),
             'link': item_data.get('itemUrl'),
             'item_id': item_data.get('itemId'),
             'rating': item_data['rating'].get('averageRating'),
             'price': item_data.get('price')            
          }
```